# Display only last 5 records from database using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanted to get recent records from database limit only to 5. I used the code below but not working. Maybe I missed something or the whole query is wrong. Please guide me. Thanks

Model

```
 public function get_comments ($id) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');  
  $this->db->from('Item_comments');
  $this->db->limit('5');
  $this->db->where(array('checklist_item_id' => $id, 'status' => 1));

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
 }
```

> Note: query works fine and get 5 records from db but I want to
>   position the recent into the bottom. Thanks

Comment: how *but not working* ?

Comment: @splash58, I updated the brief. It's working but I wanted to display the recent record in bottom

Comment: $this->db->order_by('id',"desc"); or use more reliable field for order

Comment: Or do you want get 5 first records and sort them in descending order?

Comment: Yea, I used also `DESC` but the most recently added data from database is now at the top of the result. I want it to be inserted in the bottom .

Comment: You need use subquery `select *from (your_query) t order by id desc`.  Can you write subquery in CI ?

Comment: sounds new to me @splash58.

Comment: i'we written recently - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360521/codeigniter-joining-derived-tables/37360587#37360587 It's not the same but example

Comment: @splash58, need to read the doc first :)

Comment: I didn't see anything about this in docs. But, maybe, i'm wrong

Comment: if you have a problem with subquery. sort these 5 records in php before output.

Comment: why don't you use   `return array_reverse($query->result_array());` because this will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: @AmitSarwara, yes it's working now by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last results you need to order them descending

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
```

Of course you can also use other columns instead of id.

To order your results ascending:

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "asc");
```

To reverse the resulting array:

```
$results = get_comments();
$results = array_reverse($results);
```

Or if you would like to do it in the function:

```
return array_reverse($query->result_array());
```

Comment: Yea, I used also `DESC` but the most recently added data from database is now at the top of the result. I want it to be inserted in the bottom .

Comment: Then you should use `asc` instead

Comment: `Desc` is correct but in the view, but i wanted the result in the view to be `asc`/ Ughhh hard to explain :p

Comment: You need last/recent 5 rows from DB but want to show this 5 rows as Ascending order. right?

Comment: Yes @RejoanulAlam, :)

Comment: That's because it should be `return array_reverse($query->result_array());`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function get_comments ($id) {

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT Item_comments.id i_id,Item_comments.column_name1,Item_comments.column_name2 FROM Item_comments WHERE Item_comments.checklist_item_id = ' . $id . ' AND Item_comments.status = 1 ORDER BY Item_comments.id DESC LIMIT 5) T1 ORDER BY i_id ASC';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);


  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Unknown column 'Item_comments.column_name1' in 'field list'

Comment: I changed .column_names to table fields but $id is Undefined

Comment: Is your URL like this?? `http:localhost/project_name/controller/get_comments/ID`

Comment: Yes thats the exact url

Comment: if so you will never get undefine ID error. `var_dump($id)` & debug

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function get_comments($start,$limit,$id)
{
       $condition = array('checklist_item_id' => $id,'status'=>1);
       $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');       
       $this->db->limit($limit, $start);        
       $query  = $this->db->get_where('Item_comments',$condition);          
       $rows = $query->result();    
       return $rows;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_comments ($id) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');  
  $this->db->from('Item_comments');
  $this->db->limit('5');
  $this->db->where(array('checklist_item_id' => $id, 'status' => 1));

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry but this is actually the same as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
public function get_comments ($id) {

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC'); 
  $this->db->from('Item_comments');
  $this->db->limit('0,5');
  $this->db->where(array('checklist_item_id' => $id, 'status' => 1));
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```